# How to input a value in the very middle of a matrix

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

I am trying to put a value in the middle of a matrix n*n (n being a positive odd integer) without the use of mod or disp 
Currently I have this code with mod and disp

```
function [] = centerzero(n)
 v=zeros(n,n);
 a=length(v);
 b=(size(v,2)+1)/2;
  if mod(a,2)==1
     v(b,b)=n;
     disp(v);

  end
end
```

How would I output the vector (with the very middle value in the matrix equaling n)?
Would I have to use for-loops or is their another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple function which achieves what you want is

```
function a = centerzero(n)
    a = zeros(n,n);
    m = floor((n+1)/2);
    a(m,m) = n;
end
```

and used like

```
>> centerzero(5)

ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     5     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: oh sorry but I forgot to mention that i don't want to use floor or ceil functions either

Comment: For generality I'd make this generate a simple `1` on the centre spot and then it can be multiplied by the desired constant. Otherwise this is indeed the way to go.

Comment: @TheBOI Why do you not want to use floor or ceil?

Comment: Okay I just didn't make use of the floor function but made m=(n+1)/2 and it still seems to work as it is intended to

Comment: @Antimony Because I was told that it was possible without the use of mod, disp, floor, ceil

Comment: A slightly terser version is `a((numel(a)+1)/2) = n;`

Answer (score 0):

> oh sorry but I forgot to mention that i don't want to use floor or
>   ceil functions either – TheBOI

Just remove the floor function from Chris's answer. It's just keeps things from messing up if you enter something like  5.5. you could also incorporate the modulus 2 check back in to ensure your value isn't even.